# Ограниченный набор типов для дефолтных операторов сравнения

Tags: c++, сравнение, language-lawyer, дизайн-языка, default

Почему для создания дефолтных операторов сравнения можно использовать только `(const T&)` либо `friend (const T&)` и `friend (T)` комбинации параметров https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons?

Почему нельзя сгенерить операторы с параметрами по значению в случае функции-члена? Почему нельзя сгенерить операторы с неконстантными ссылками, rvalue-ссылками?

Comment: если  использовать оба варианта с типами аргумента `(T const &)` и `(T)`, то происходит неопределённость, какой из них использовать. Разрешается только собственный `(T)` **или (XOR)** `(T const &)`. А если хотите `= default`, то в компиляторе оставили `(T const &)`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe вопрос не в том, чтобы использовать несколько вариантов одновременно, а в том, почему доступны именно такие варианты и недоступны другие

Comment: ¿Почему нельзя? неконстантные ссылки, rvalue-ссылки прекрасно биндятся к `const T&` или к `T` при наличии копирующего конструктора.

Comment: @user7860670 имелось в виду, почему нельзя сгенерить такие операторы

Comment: ¿Так а зачем это может понадобится, если существующие покрывают все потребности?

Comment: @user7860670 может мы хотим сгенерить операторы, которые не будут работать для lvalue. И почему различие для friend и функции-члена?

Comment: Сигнатуры гомогенные - они либо принимают оба аргумента по ссылке, либо оба по значению. Метод класса не может принимать оба аргумента по значению. А если хочется сгенерировать какие-то экзотические операторы, которые не будут работать для lvalue, то для этого их можно реализовать вручную.

Comment: как всегда в C++ фичи нет потому что никто на ней не настоял.
Сначала вообще было только `const T&`, а потом добавили by-value потому что автор http://wg21.link/p1946 сказал, что ему очень нужно.